# converting pdf to text using pdftotext

Tags: mouse, pdf

Is there any way by which i can find position of text selecting cursor in ubuntu 12.04?Can we use pdftotext to convert pdffile to text depending on those coordinates.

Comment: pdftotext provides the `-layout` option that may help you to parse the generated txt file

Answer (score 0):

```
pdftotext -layout input.pdf output.txt
```

**pdftotext screws up the output use pdfBox (java)** .

(OR)

If you have a Google account, you can use Google Docs to upload the PDF and transform it into editable text

Comment: I am not able to find a java library for ubuntu.